# In RoR, how do I get the status code when requesting a web page through a proxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, response, status, socks

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  How do I get the status code when making a request?  I’m trying the below

```
  uri = URI(url)
  content = nil
  status = nil
  content_type = nil
  res1 = Net::HTTP.SOCKSProxy('127.0.0.1', 50001).start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
    puts "launching #{uri.path}"
    resp = http.get(uri.path)
    status = resp.status
    content = resp.content
    content_type = resp['content-type']
  end
```

but its resulting in the below error.  I can clearly see its a 403, but I would like to have that nice and neat within a variable, or at least have some kind of error I can catch

```
Error during processing: undefined method `status' for #<Net::HTTPForbidden 403 Forbidden readbody=true>
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/helpers/webpage_helper.rb:77:in `block in get_content'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:584:in `start'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/helpers/webpage_helper.rb:74:in `get_content'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `resp.code`.

One way to find out is to use the `pry` gem.  Once installed you can put `binding.pry` just after your `http.get` line and run your code. When it hits the pry line it will stop executing and open up a IRB prompt and then you can play around with `resp` directly trying different things.  One really nifty feature is you can `cd resp` and are now "in" the object itself.  Type `ls` and you can see all the methods available.  Makes figuring this sort of thing out much easier.